# For $A$ is irreducible, prove: $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$

Tags: matrices, vectors

Let $A$ be a given irreducible non-negative $n \times n$ matrix.

Let $x \in R^n$ be a non-negative vector

How do I prove that $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$?

I know that if A is invertible, this implies $x=0$, but in this case, I doubt whether A is irreducible implies A is invertible?

Comment: What does a "non-negative vector" mean? That all entries are non-negative?

Comment: @DietrichBurde is there a connection with A is irreducible and A is invertible?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it means $x_i \geq 0$ for $1 \geq i \geq n$

Comment: @RobinBakker No, invertible and irreducible are not related in this way. In fact, we need a precise definition for this question. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the proof [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=46S4CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA418&lpg=PA418&dq=irreducible+matrix+non-negative+implies+Ax%3D0+then+x%3D0&source=bl&ots=lhrhgurr5G&sig=SSqjH28MjzZ3hbSCvvyaSdH9jWc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHzNnfvqLXAhUKLlAKHaGcBAwQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=irreducible%20matrix%20non-negative%20implies%20Ax%3D0%20then%20x%3D0&f=false), Lemma $8.10$. It is straightforward from the definition. So the crucial point, actually, *is* the right definition of *irreducible*. This is given in Definition $8.9$ of this book, "The Mathematics of Networks of Linear Systems". Unfortunately this definition is a bit too long for copying it here, so I hope the link is fine.